# Disable ListBox items in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

i want to disable an key items in listbox, here:

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<A, List<B>> result) {
            listBoxB.clear();
            listBoxB.addItem("-select-", "0");
            for(Entry<A,List<B>> iterator:result.entrySet()) {
                String key=String.valueOf(iterator.getKey().getName());
                List<B> list=iterator.getValue();
                listBoxB.addItem("-"+key+"-", "0");
                for (B b : list) {
                    listBoxB.addItem(b.getName(),
                            String.valueOf(b.getId()));

                    if (selectedB == b.getId()) {
                        listBoxB.setSelectedIndex(listBoxB.getItemCount()-1);
                    }
                }
```

i can only disable the "select" "0" item, but not the other key items with value "0" when i set the attribute to index=0 as "disabled".
i have following structure in listbox, and want diasable only Bitem1,NextBitem,... these are not static, it changeable:

```
-select-
    -Bitem1-
someitem
someitem
....
    -NextBitem-
someanotheritem
...
```

any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `OptGroupElement`, eg.:

```
OptGroupElement oge = Document.get().createOptGroupElement();   // not selectable
oge.setLabel( "B item 1" ):
oge.appendChild( ... /* Your selectable items */ )
...

// more opt groups here perhaps.
// ...

SelectElement se = listBox.getElement().cast();  // get listbox selection element
se.appendChild( oge ); // ...and add the option group(s).
...
```

Cheers,

Comment: I don't quite understand your code snippet, but I'll venture a guess and say don't add the OptGroup if the `innerEntry.getValue()` list is empty.